# Replacement of backslash with forward slash

Tags: batch-file

Can anyone help me understand what is wrong with following code

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set currentDirectory = %CD%
set "currentDirectory = %currentDirectory:\=/%"
```

It doesn't seem to be replacing the forward slash with backward slash

Comment: Remove spaces around the _Equals Sign_ `=`.

Answer (score 1):

When `set`ting variables, you need to know that variables include the whitespace before and after the `=` You should therefore have no spaces. The below example is also shorter as we do not have to set `currentDirectory` twice:

```
@echo off
set "currentDirectory=%cd:\=/%"
```